# Black screen, no bios, advice appreciated

Tags: laptop, bios

A neighbour handed me her HP Pavilion dv4 laptop.  The screen is black and no bios (or anything else) appears after starting.  The LEDs for audio controls and WIFI are all illuminated constantly and the scroll and capslock key LEDs flash slowly on and off, continuously.  The fan starts and continues running after a minute or two.  Esc/F2 after power-on does nothing.

Apart from buying a new laptop, does anyone have any faultfinding tips in this situation?

Comment: According to this HP forum: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Hp-pavillion-dv4-not-booting-black-screen-and-blinking-LEDs/td-p/1673191 .. some users suggested removing the battery and trying it direct plugged into the wall

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for your situation. A Corrupted BIOS firmware is probably one of the most troublesome and scariest experience for any PC user. But you will be glad to know that there is still hope even on such a dead end. Reprogramming your BIOS firmware by forcing a BIOS crisis recovery on your machine may be your last option. Basically you can force a BIOS flash even with an ideally dead PC given that you can enter into BIOS crisis recovery. You will need to make a bootable USB thumb drive with your *specific BIOS firmware files (with a few changes to the file names). You will then need to force the PC into crisis recovery at start up. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> keys or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for some models.

Keep in mind that there is no guarantee this procedure will revive all PC models but a good record of HP laptops get through just fine. So here is a link to such a procedure for your HP DV4. 
http://neighborhoodsupport.net/?x=entry:entry121218-092226
Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like it is the CPU that has failed according to the single flash from the caps/numlock lights.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a high number of laptops aged sooner or later. Hp or Compaq lacks of long service life due to this flaw: It seems that a number of CPU´s do not have Pb in the soldering points. The use of the pc, heats and cools, such soldering points, make them prone to break. The simpthoms before final fault are: 1.-Too slow performance. 2.-Disconnection of DVD writer, speakers, no DVD detection. etc. 3.- If you add more RAM, suddenly it won´t start. 4.-Even some laptops if are pressed with the hand, I had witnessed that can start alive, because I am pushing in contact again and temporarly, CPU against MOBO. 
So if this is your case, do not spend more time and money, and try to sell in parts your equipment.

Good Luck.